# change data in struct

Tags: c, struct, syntax

I try to write a function to change data in a struct.  Here are part of my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#define THREADNUM 20 

pthread_mutex_t DeviceMutex ;
struct VirtualPCB
{
    int tid;
    int handlePriority;
    int arrivetime;
    int waittime;
    int runtime;
    int visited;
    int tempruntime;
    int finishtime;
}PCBs[THREADNUM];


void initPCB()
{
    int n;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(n =0;n<THREADNUM;n++)
    {

        PCBs[n].tid = n + 1;
        PCBs[n].handlePriority = 1 + rand()%19;
        PCBs[n].arrivetime = 1 + rand()%19;
        PCBs[n].tempruntime=PCBs[n].runtime = 1 + rand()%19;
        PCBs[n].waittime = 0;
        PCBs[n].visited =0;
        PCBs[n].finishtime = PCBs[n].arrivetime + PCBs[n].runtime;
    }
}

void change(PCBs[THREADNUM],int i, int j)
{
    int temp;
    temp = PCBs[i].arrivetime;
    PCBs[i].arrivetime = PCBs[j].arrivetime;
    PCBs[j].arrivetime = temp;
    temp = PCBs[i].runtime;
    PCBs[i].runtime = PCBs[j].runtime;
    PCBs[j].runtime = temp;
    temp = PCBs[i].finishtime;
    PCBs[i].finishtime = PCBs[j].finishtime;
}
```

but there is an error.

> "error:expected declaration specifier or '...'

before `PCBs`. I have searched the Internet, but I can not find an effective way. Can you tell me how to correct them?

Comment: On which line(s) do you see this error?

Comment: void change(PCBs[THREADNUM],int i, int j). I already correct the error .thank you all the same

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for function definition is wrong. You need to change

```
  void change(PCBs[THREADNUM],int i, int j) { ....
```

to

```
  void change(struct VirtualPCB PCBs[THREADNUM],int i, int j) { ...
```

or

```
void change(struct VirtualPCB PCBs[ ],int i, int j) {....
```

Comment: ..because you are now using a variable in your definition instead of a type.

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid syntax for defining a function:

```
void change(PCBs[THREADNUM],int i, int j)
```

The first parameter need a type which you didn't specify:

```
void change(struct VirtualPCB PCBs[THREADNUM],int i, int j)
```